# Rebuild logistic regression model without regularisation sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, scikit-learn, lasso, regularization

favorite
I built a logistic regression model using sklearn on 80+ features. After regularisation (L1) there were 10 non-zero features left. I want to turn this model into a production model but I don't want to do all the variable modifications I done for the 80+ variables.

I took the variables left in from the regularised model, done all the feature transformations (on the 10 variables) and then build a un-regularised logistic regression using `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C = 1e10)`.

However, I am getting very different coefficients and as a result, the model doesn't perform as well.

How can I replicate the original model but without having to recode 80+ variables but just use the ones that were left over after regularisation?

Comment: You know the coefficients of the model you want, what is the need for refitting? You have a fit object, why exactly do you need another one?

Comment: Because ultimately I need to build it with pyspark (mllib).

Comment: the computational cost for linear model is really low, even with 800 features, in production the calculation will take no time. why are you interested to "simplify"?

Comment: I would just rather not have to recode 80+ variables in pyspark but rather just do 10. It's a time saving thing.

Comment: Since you know the 10 variables you want to keep, and you know the parameter estimates, and you know how logistic regression makes predictions, what is the issue here?  It should be simple to code the computation of the predictions in pyspark.  You don't need to fit the model in pyspark, that's vastly overcomplicating the problem.